# Updating texture and geometry in three.js

Tags: dynamic, three.js, texture-mapping

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way of getting a callback once a texture has been updated? I'm swapping the geometry in the scene but sharing the same changing underlying texture based on a canvas and I'm noticing random corruption that eventually disappears as the program runs. I think this is as a result of thrashing that is causing the geometry changes to become unsynchronized with the texture updates.

So I realize the established mechanism is to set is needsUpdate = true on the texture and material, but can I know when that update has been applied so that I can add the new geometry to the scene? I think I am adding the geometry before that update actually gets to the gpu and using the old texture for random frames.  Is this possible, or does the texture update definitely get processed before the scene is drawn?

If you can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Additionally I've added an update event listener to the material, which gets called frequently, but I still end up with the same issues relating to the texture update happening after the geometry has been updated.

Here is an example of what I mean, some code removed. The general idea is to share the same texture / material among many generated objects. Update the canvas, and then add the new object into the scene. This for the most part works under chrome, but occasionally glitches where a frame has the previous texture applied.

```
var material, texture, texture_canvas, context;

var frames = [];
var total_frames = 24;
var last_frame = undefined;
var current_frame = 0;
var scene;


function init() {

    // initialize scene, etc
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Set up render etc, omitted

    texture_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    texture_canvas.height = 1024;
    texgture_canvas.width = 1024;

    context = texture_canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.fillRect( 0, 0,
        texture_canvas.width,
        texture_canvas.height );

    texture = new THREE.Texture( this.texture_canvas );
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.generateMipmaps = false;

    material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: texture } );

    for (var i=0; i<total_frames; i++) {
         var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( generate_geometry(), material );
         frames.push(mesh);
    }

}

function animate() {


    if (last_frame) {
        scene.remove(frames[last_frame]);
    }
    // Update / generate new canvas
    context.drawImage( generate_image(), 0, 0 );
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    material.needsUpdate = true;
    frames[current_frame].uvsNeedUpdate = true;
    scene.add(frames[current_frame % total_frames]);
    last_frame = current_frame;
    current_frame++;
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to share some code of what you have done so far. So, we will be able to better understand, what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: I've added some example code that I think captures the problem.